# Microsoft NLB with https

Tags: iis-8, nlb

I have 2 servers controlled via NLB with 1 website using https currently and it's working great.  I'd like to add another IIS website using a new IP address and new SSL cert.   To get that to work with NLB,  do i need to create a new NLB cluster for the new IP address,  or can i add the new public IP to the existing cluster?

-Randy

Comment: It is rare that you need a new IP address. Can you check SNI support and see if you can use that to configure multiple HTTPS sites on the same IP address:port? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Comment: Interesting @LexLi,   but it looks like that doesn';t work with IE and i still have to support IE.   Do you know how to setup NLB with separate IP addresses to support IE and HTTPS?

Comment: It only fails to work for any browsers on Windows XP. If you no longer need to support Windows XP, then don't waste your time any more.

Comment: I did get that to work, so thanks for that information,  but unfortunately we still have some XP clients using IE.